# %c specifier char limit capped in C, how to avoid that?

Tags: c, arrays, char, character, limit

I am running into a problem when I'm trying to output the fractional part of a hexadecimal number.

Basically, with the following code:

```
float d2h(float decimal, float fraction) {
  int i = 0;
  char hex[17] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                   'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', '\0' };
  int temp = (int) decimal;
  int j;
  for (j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
    fraction = fraction - (int) fraction;
    displayFractionHex[j] = hex[(int) (fraction * 16)];
    fraction *= 16;
  }
  for (i = sizeof(displayDecimalHex) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    displayDecimalHex[i] = hex[temp % 16];
    temp /= 16;
  }
  int n;
  if ((n = strspn(displayDecimalHex, "0")) != 0
      && displayDecimalHex[n] != '\0')        // strspn() - Reference
    printf("%s", &displayDecimalHex[n]);
  printf(".");
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    printf("%c", displayFractionHex[i]);
  }
}
```

I get the output `222.74BC0000000000000000`, and I obviously want the fractional part of the hex number to display more characters.

However, when I try change the last `printf` statement to a `%s` specifier instead of `%c`, my program crashes.

I have attempted copying the array to another one, unfortunately to no avail.

Comment: What's your input? Where are `displayFractionHex` and `displayDecimalHex` declared?

Comment: char displayDecimalHex[30], displayFractionHex[30]; -- at the very top of the code.

Comment: my input is a float number, which is then divided into its decimal part and its fractional part

Comment: And what two floats did you pass into this function to get the output above, and what output did you expect?

Comment: well, my input was 546.456, thus the decimal float is 546 and the fractional float is 0.456

Comment: expected output is something along the lines of 222.74bc6a7ef9d...

Comment: `(int) fraction` is a problem if `fraction` much outside the `int` range.  Better to use `truncf(fraction)`.

Comment: You do realise that it's only printing 20 characters because *you told it to print 20 characters*, right?

Comment: @chux thank you, I will try that out now

Comment: @immibis the problem is not that it's only printing 20 characters -- the problem is that out of the 20 characters, 4 of them are only relevant, regardless of the input

Comment: Note: `float d2h()` has problems that will not generate the exact answer including  1) `fraction = fraction - (int) fraction;`  2) `int temp = (int) decimal;`.  Do not use `(int)`.

Comment: You should take a look at the `%a` printf format code. It might save you a lot of work. By the way, your function claims to return a float, but doesn't. If you compiled with warnings enabled, (`-Wall` in gcc), you could fix stuff like that before it bites you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP commented:

> expected output is something along the lines of 222.74bc6a7ef9d...

Typical `float` has about 24 binary digits of precision as does `222.74BC000000...`".

For higher precision use, `double`.

Use `printf("%a\n%a\n", (float) 546.456, 546.456);` for example to see the difference.

```
0x1.113a5ep+9
0x1.113a5e353f7cfp+9
```

---

To be clear, "thus the decimal float is 546 and the fractional float is 0.456" is incorrect.  The input to `d2h(float decimal)` was *not* `546.456`, but the closest representable `float` to it exactly `546.4559936523437500...` and *that* `float` is exactly `222.74BC` in hex FP.

Comment: however, it now displays 222.74BC6A7EF9E000000000 -- is there a way to make it display even more characters?

Comment: @zorrooo `long double`?  Note that `546.456` to FP does not typically give you _exactly_ 546.456,